# Install @angular/cli on VM windows offline

Tags: angular, installation, virtual-machine, offline, angular12

I am a young developer, and I would like to know if anyone knows a method to install **@angular/cli**, on a windows virtual machine which is not connected to the internet?

It's been several days since I have this problem and I can not find a real solution.
Thank you so much !

Comment: Where would you want to get it from..?

Comment: You need to create your own npm registry and set your npm config to point there in your VM. You may checkout [this](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio)

Comment: Ok thanks for your answers, MikeOne if i download angular/cli on my computer(online), and i take all files and directories generated by angular, and i put all of this on my vm, can i install angular/cli like this ?

Comment: Eldar how can i create a npm registry ? if it is on github i could not access it without online connection, is it true ?